# Vue composition API store

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I was wondering if it was possible with the new Vue composition API to store all the `ref()` in one big object and use that instead of a vuex store. It would certainly take away the need for `mutations`, `actions`, ... and probably be faster too.

So in short, is it possible to have one place for storing reactive properties that will share the same state between different components?

I know it's possible to have reusable code or functions that can be shared between different components. But they always instantiate a new object I believe. It would be great if they would depend on one single source of truth for a specific object. Maybe I'm mixing things up...

Comment: I don't see why that won't work, but the need for mutations and actions will not go away. Mutations/Actions are gatekeepers, but they are more important from a data flow point of view. A mutation/action can do validation and parsing. This need doesn't go away by using composition API.

Comment: Here is a guide that I used. Basically you just create a ref variable outside of your exported function. https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/state-management-with-composition-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reactive` instead of `ref`.

For eg.

- You can use

```
    export const rctStore = reactive({
      loading: false,
      list: [],
      messages: []
    })
```

- Instead of

```
    export const loading = ref(false)
    export const list = ref([])
    export const messages = ref([])
```

Cheers!